# Problem with specifying enumeration value types

Tags: scala

I have a problem with specifying types for enumeration values (instances of `scala.Enumeration`) in functions. This originally arises from my need to serialize enumeration objects in database, but I've extracted the problematic code in the following example:

```
object EnumerationTypes {

  class EnumerationProcessor[E <: Enumeration](enum: E, value: E#Value) {
    def process: E#Value = {
      value
    }
  }

  object Enum extends Enumeration {
    type EnumValue = Value

    val a = Value(1, "a")
    val b = Value(2, "b")
  }

  case class Obj(val flag: Enum.EnumValue)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val processor = new EnumerationProcessor(Enum, Enum.a)
    val obj = Obj(processor.process)
  }
}
```

It leads to the following compilation error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : EnumerationTypes.Enum#Value
 required: EnumerationTypes.Enum.EnumValue
    val obj = Obj(processor.process)
```

While this works ok:

```
object EnumerationTypesOk {

  class EnumerationProcessor[E <: Enumeration](enum: E, value: E#Value) {
    def process: E#Value = {
      value
    }
  }

  class Enum extends Enumeration {
    type EnumValue = Value

    val a = Value(1, "a")
    val b = Value(2, "b")
  }
  object Enum extends Enum

  case class Obj(val flag: Enum#EnumValue)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val processor = new EnumerationProcessor(Enum, Enum.a)
    val obj = Obj(processor.process)
  }
}
```

But I don't want my code to be looks like this (first define class and then its singleton instance).

So the problem: how I can make `value` type be exactly the `enum.EnumValue`? While it seems impossible, because types cannot depend on concrete values, maybe there are some tricks to achieve desired effect with no additional boilerplate.

Comment: Related question on scala-user mailing list: http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Making-combinations-td3017320.html

Comment: Your solution version 1 seems to work fine in scala 2.11.7

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Looks like you just need to help the type inferencer a bit to get your first solution working:

```
val processor = new EnumerationProcessor[Enum.type](Enum, Enum.a)
```

Hopefully someone smarter than I am will come along and explain why.

**Before the OP's clarifying comment:**

```
object EnumerationTypes {

   class EnumerationProcessor[E <: Enumeration, V <: E#Value](enum: E, value: V) {
      def process: V = {
        value
      }
   } 

   object Enum extends Enumeration {
      type EnumValue = Value

      val a = Value(1, "a")
      val b = Value(2, "b")
   }

   case class Obj(val flag: Enum.EnumValue)

   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val processor = new EnumerationProcessor(Enum, Enum.a)
      val obj = Obj(processor.process)
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solutions is `V` is not compatible with `E.Value` — and if I want to do inside processor something like `enum.values.find { _ == value }` it will not typecheck.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential solution is to define a mixin that allows you to create a 'processor' for a particular Enumeration instance:

```
object EnumerationTypes {
   trait EnumerationProcessor { self: Enumeration =>
      def processor(value: self.Value): () => self.Value = () => { 
         value 
      }
   }

   object Enum extends Enumeration with EnumerationProcessor {
      type EnumValue = Value

      val a = Value(1, "a")
      val b = Value(2, "b")
   }

   case class Obj(val flag: Enum.EnumValue)

   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val processor = Enum.processor(Enum.a)
      val obj = Obj(processor())
   }
}
```